# Is there any function in python to rename the column permanently

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory, rename

As I am working on Car_sales data I am renaming a column name horsepower as hp and when I am run this code it is working but after when I am fetching that same dataset The column name become same as horsepower not as hp . I am working on google colab and doing feature engineering

df.rename(columns={'horsepower':'hp'})

I want that column name to be change as hp permanently.

Answer (score 1):

`df = df.rename(columns={'horsepower': 'hp'})`

or

`df.rename(columns={'horsepower': 'hp'}, inplace=True)`

Here, if your rename is done "inplace" then changes are stored in the df, otherwise you need to redefine the variable to store these changes.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**